# WordPress plugin: finding the <!--more--> in the_content

Tags: filter, wordpress

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that filters **the_content**, and I'd like to make use of the `<!--more-->` tag, but it appears that it has been stripped out by the time it reaches me. This appears to be not a filter, but a function of the way WordPress works.

I could of course resort to reloading the already-loaded content from the database, but that sounds like it might cause other troubles. Is there any good way for me to get the raw content without the `<!--more-->` removed?

Comment: Looks like you were answered over on [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/271798) - did that solution work for you?

Comment: I suppose it's an option - the $post contains the original post before it was processed, and if I revert to that then I can use both the <!--more--> and the unshortened post. But I worry about what other processing this may bypass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are, by the time your plugin runs, `<!--more-->` has been converted to `<span id="more-1"></span>`

This is what I use in my plugin, which injects some markup immediately after the `<!--more-->` tag:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'inject_content_filter', 999);

function inject_content_filter($content) {
  $myMarkup = "my markup here<br>";
  $content = preg_replace('/<span id\=\"(more\-\d+)"><\/span>/', '<span id="\1"></span>'."\n\n". $myMarkup ."\n\n", $content);
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: So it does. I hadn't noticed that!

Now I just need to find out how to stop it removing the section after the more, when it's on listing pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follow code:

The !is_single() will avoid display the more link in the View Post page.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_post_content');
function filter_post_content($content,$post_id='') {

        if ($post_id=='') {
            global $post;
            $post_id = $post->ID;
        }

        // Check for the "more" tags
        $more_pos = strpos($filtered_content, '<!--more-->');
        if ($more_pos && !is_single()) {
            $filtered_content = substr($filtered_content, 0, $more_pos);

            $replace_by = '<a href="' . get_permalink($post_id) . '#more-' . $post_id 
                    . '" class="more-link">Read More <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a>';

            $filtered_content = $filtered_content . $replace_by;
        }

        return $filtered_content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Frank Farmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/893895/4519702) I solved to add thumbnail photo after the generated more tag (`<span id="more-...`) in single.php file with this:

```
// change more tag to post's thumbnail in single.php
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
{
    if(has_post_thumbnail())
    {
        $post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail', array('class'=>'img img-responsive img-thumbnail', 'style'=>'margin-top:5px;'));
        $content = preg_replace('/<span id\=\"(more\-\d+)"><\/span>/', '<span id="\1"></span>'.$post_thumbnail, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}, 999);
```